# Using include in framelayout, how can i let the activities work ?

Tags: android, tabs, include

i am using this code

```
package com.example.prufa;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TabHost;
import android.widget.TabHost.TabSpec;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TabHost tabHost=(TabHost)findViewById(R.id.tabHost);
        tabHost.setup();

        TabSpec spec1=tabHost.newTabSpec("Sími");
        spec1.setContent(R.id.Sími);
        spec1.setIndicator("Sími");

        TabSpec spec2=tabHost.newTabSpec("Sms");
        spec2.setIndicator("Sms");
        spec2.setContent(R.id.Sms);

        TabSpec spec3=tabHost.newTabSpec("Net");
        spec3.setIndicator("Net");
        spec3.setContent(R.id.Net);

        TabSpec spec4=tabHost.newTabSpec("Greina");
        spec4.setIndicator("Greina");
        spec4.setContent(R.id.Greina);

        tabHost.addTab(spec1);
        tabHost.addTab(spec2);
        tabHost.addTab(spec3);
        tabHost.addTab(spec4);


    }
```

with this xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tabHost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >


    <TabWidget
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@android:id/tabs"
    />

        <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bScan"
        android:layout_below="@+android:id/tabs" >


        <include
            android:id="@+id/Sími"
            layout="@layout/activity_simi" />

        <include
            android:id="@+id/Sms"
            layout="@layout/activity_sms" />


        <include
            android:id="@+id/Net"
            layout="@layout/activity_net" />

        <include
            android:id="@+id/Greina"
            layout="@layout/activity_greina" />

     <LinearLayout
         android:id="@+id/Sími"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="340dp"
         android:orientation="vertical"
         android:paddingTop="60px" >
     </LinearLayout>

     <LinearLayout
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/Sms"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingTop="60px"
     >

     </LinearLayout>

      <LinearLayout
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/Net"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingTop="60px"
     >

     </LinearLayout>

     <LinearLayout
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/Greina"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingTop="60px"
     >


     </LinearLayout>
     </FrameLayout>

    </TabHost>
```

I have 4 tabs inside the main activity and i am using include so i can create 4 other activitys and work with each tab inside these activities. I have to do something in the Mainactivity file so i can do this. But i dont know how i can do this. I am trying to move the control from the Mainactivity to the other activity where i am working on the tabs. I can work with the xml file now for each tab, but i cant work with the activity.

Comment: Can you comment if the question makes no sense. If you dont understand my problem

Answer (score 2):

If I understand what you wanna do, you have to use just the include, maybe should work.

```
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/tabHost"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TabWidget
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@android:id/tabs"/>

    <FrameLayout
    android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/bScan"
    android:layout_below="@+android:id/tabs" >

        <include
            android:id="@+id/Sími"
            layout="@layout/activity_simi" />

        <include
            android:id="@+id/Sms"
            layout="@layout/activity_sms" />

        <include
           android:id="@+id/Net"
           layout="@layout/activity_net" />

       <include
           android:id="@+id/Greina"
           layout="@layout/activity_greina" />

   </FrameLayout>

</TabHost>
```

But, did you try to use Fragments instead activities? Essentially, fragments is piece of ui code that behaves like an activity. I think it is the best fit for you code. Check out the developers page:

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Hope I helped.